# Why won't my stylesheet external link won't work? Summary in the text

Tags: css

so this is how I did it but for some reason, it won't make a difference in what I do but this stylesheet won't work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
    ALKALINE ENERGY
    </title>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css">
</head>
```

Comment: how you organize your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a link to the external stylesheet in order for that stylesheet to be applied to anything!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="url_to_your_stylesheet.css">
```